# Error while updating ThingSpeak using SIM808

Tags: shields, gsm, rs232

im trying to update ThingSpeak from a SIM808 but I'm getting a network error. Please check below and let me know if there is anything wrong in my methodology.

I'm using terminal.exe to send commands via RS232.

```
AT
OK
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,5 //connected in roaming
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"
OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","www" //VODAFONE INDIA "www" is APN (as per the operator)
OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"USER","" //blank (as per the operator)
OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"PWD","" //blank  (as per the operator)
AT+SAPBR=1,1
OK
AT+HTTPINIT
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CID","1"
OK
AT+HTTPARA="URL","https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=MY_KEY&field1=VALUE"
OK
AT+HTTPACTION=0
+HTTPACTION: 0,603,0
```

Note: while I'm typing in the browser url box, https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=MY_KEY&field1=VALUE, I can update my field. I can make calls, send SMS. I have an internet pack.

Please help.

Comment: You're using HTTP commands to perform an HTTPS request. You need to use the HTTPS commands instead. Read the SIM808 manual for the right commands.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69513173/8119511

Answer (score 1):

It worked with changing AT+HTTPARA="URL","http://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=MY_KEY&field1=VALUE" (from https:// to http://)

Answer (score 0):

You have to send this command: AT+HTTPSSL=1